# Spring with Mockito: two strategies?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

JavaDoc for `@InjectMocks` says:

> If the object is successfully created with the constructor, then
>   Mockito won't try the other strategies.

but I have some doubts. Here's why:

```
public class MyBean {
  private String path = "home";
  public void setPath(String path) { this.path = path; }
  public String path() { return path; }
}

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private MyBean myBean;

    public HomeController(MyBean myBean) {

        System.out.println("HomeController(MyBean myBean)"); // always displays!!!

        // either:  <--- case 1
        MyBean bean = new MyBean();
        bean.setPath("home-modified");
        this.myBean = bean;

        // or:      <--- case 2
        this.myBean = null;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println(myBean);
        return myBean.path();
    }
}
```

Causes the following test to pass:

```
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Spy private MyBean myBean;
    @InjectMocks private HomeController controller; 

    @Before
    public void initAnnotations() { MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); }

    @Test
    public void testAutowired() {
        assertThat(controller.home(), is("home"));
    }
}
```

But why `myBean` never becomes `null` (case 2) or represents my custom object (case 1)? Looks like a violation of its own JavaDoc by Mockito? Or do I miss something?

### Update: the same things with setters

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private  MyBean myBean;

    public HomeController(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
        System.out.println("HomeController(MyBean myBean)");
    }

    public void setMyBean(MyBean myBean) {
        System.out.println("setMyBean(MyBean myBean)");
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return myBean.path();
    }
}
```

Displays:

```
HomeController(MyBean myBean)
setMyBean(MyBean myBean)
```

Which is obviously "another strategy".

Comment: Are you running it with the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`?

Comment: @MikeKobit No, I thought `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` was enough.

Comment: Why do you use @Spy on the MyBean myBean field? I was expecting either a Mock, or a normal instance which is spied, to be created, e.g.:

    `@Mock private MyBean myBean;`

or

    `@Spy private MyBean myBean = new MyBean();`

Comment: @blagerweij See [JavaDoc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Spy.html) that allowes it.

Comment: Not sure how did you get these results. I just tried it and got a `null`. What version of Mockito are you using?

Comment: In the version with setter: `myBean = myBean;` must be `this.myBean = myBean;`

Comment: @KhalidAlqinyah mockito-all v1.10.8

Comment: @gontard Fixed. Same result.